# Monitorizar stock productos Decathlon con Python

Tags: python

Estaba desarrollando este script para monitorizar el stock de los productos, y enviar un correo.
El caso és que todos los productos tienen un json con este formato:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{   "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
    "@type": "product",
    "brand": "DOMYOS",
    "name": "Rack cross training musculación Domyos 900 multifunción",
    "productID": "171335",
    "description": "¡Una sala de musculación completa con un único producto! Realiza con absoluta seguridad sentadillas, tracciones, tracciones con polea (alta/baja) y desarrollo tumbado (combinado con nuestros bancos). ",
    "offers":[
    
        
            {"@type": "Offer",
            "sku": "2524417",
            "price": "499.99",
            "priceCurrency": "EUR",
            "availability": "http://schema.org/OutOfStock",
            "itemCondition": "http://www.schema.org/NewCondition",
            "image": "https://contents.mediadecathlon.com/p1615093/k$71132c53364787d1b3edb1bbeef1ae66/sq/Rack+cross+training+musculaci+n+Domyos+900+multifunci+n.jpg",
            "seller": {
                "name": "DECATHLON",
                "@type": "Organization"
            }
        }
         
    ]
    
    
    ,"aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "aggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.52",
        "reviewCount": "302"    
    }   
    
    
}
</script>
```

Como podemos ver encontramos en **offers**, el atributo **availability**. La intención es monitorizar este valor para que cuando sea distinto a "OutOfStock" me envie un correo.

He intentado obtener este valor con el siguiente código, pero no logro obtener dicho valor, siempre me devuelve error de noneType:

```
import requests
import re
import smtplib

urls = ['https://www.decathlon.es/es/p/suelo-losas-puzzle-gimnasio-domyos-df920-gris-x4/_/R-p-7742?mc=8224362']

def main():
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url)
            match = re.search('availability.+org\/(.*?)"', r.text)
            #Send mail if match.group(1) != "OutOfStock"
            print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))

def send_mail(link):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('user','password')
    subject = 'Ya esta disponible'
    body = link
    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"
    server.sendmail(
        'origin email',
        'destiny email',
        msg
    )
    print("send")
    server.quit()


main()
```

Como podies ver en el output, és como si no encontrara ningun valor, pero si accedemos al link del producto i vemos el código fuente de la página, lo podemos ver sin ningún problema.

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "scraper.py", line 13, in main
    print("url: {:<70}, status: {}".format(r.url, match.group(1)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Edit:
Si ejecuto el script múltiples veces, en algunas ocasiones me devuelve el output esperado.

```
url: https://www.decathlon.es/es/p/suelo-losas-puzzle-gimnasio-domyos-df920-gris-x4/_/R-p-7742?mc=8224362, status: InStock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente no encuentra ningún valor, porque ante la petición que hace tu código decathlon no devuelve la web del producto. Si pruebas a imprimir por pantalla directamente el valor que te devuelve req.get(url) verás que es algo así como `request[403]`. 403 en este caso significa FORBIDDEN. Vamos, que la web de decathlon ve algo raro en tu petición y no te da la respuesta que esperas.

Para conseguir una buena respuesta tienes que hacer que tu petición se parezca un poco más a la que haría el navegador. En concreto, el navegador pasa unos cuantos headers para dar más información al servidor de decathlon acerca de la petición. Una buena opción es averiguar los headers exactos que tu navegador pone a la petición, copiarlos y pegarlos en el código python.

Te pongo mi ejemplo:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'www.decathlon.es',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.decathlon.es/es/browse/c0-deportes/c1-musculacion/c3-kit-mancuernas/_/N-b22lug',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
}
```

esos serían los headers, a la hora de hacer la petición tienes que pasarlos como argumento así:

```
r = req.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Y ya estaría. No te he pasado todos mis headers porque algunos contienen información sensible. Si con esos no te funciona prueba a encontrar los que pone tu navegador. Aquí puedes ver cómo hacerlo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489386/python-requests-403-forbidden

No te olvides de contestar si te funciona

Comment: Finalmente usé PHP, y le hago peticiones mediante un cron-job cada 10 minutos. Aún y así, he testeado los headers que me has pasado y parece que funcionan. En el caso de PHP tuve de desactivar el SSL.